# getting ActiveRecord errors when using mongoid and Sql on Ironworker files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid, ironworker

(I am relatively new to Rails)

I have a file (Ruby) I am running/uploading through Ironworker that is currently using MySql (activeRecord) for database.
ALl works fine, but We now have a need for a new (additional) Model that will use Mongoid that will also be included in our code uploaded to IronWorker.
When I include the following line merge_gem 'mongoid' to my IronWorker file I get:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Specifying an empty prefix/suffix for an attribute method is no longer necessary. If the un-prefixed/suffixed version of the method has not been defined when `define_attribute_methods` is called, it will be defined automatically. (called from block in  at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:9)

DEPRECATION WARNING: synchronize is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 3.2. (called from  at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:298)
DEPRECATION WARNING: define_attr_method is deprecated and will be removed without replacement. (called from set_table_name at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:660)
DEPRECATION WARNING: define_attr_method is deprecated and will be removed without replacement. (called from set_locking_column at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:150)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:82:in `define_read_method': uninitialized constant ActiveModel::AttributeMethods::COMPILABLE_REGEXP (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:42:in`define_method_attribute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:35:in `define_method_attribute'
    from /task/gems/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:267:in`block in define_attribute_method'
    from /task/gems/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:260:in `each'
    from /task/gems/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:260:in`define_attribute_method'
    from /task/gems/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:256:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
    from /task/gems/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:256:in`each'
    from /task/gems/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:256:in `define_attribute_methods'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:14:in`define_attribute_methods'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:65:in `respond_to?'
    from /task/gems/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:398:in`__run_callback'
    from /task/gems/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_find_callbacks'
    from /task/gems/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1617:in `init_with'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:959:in`instantiate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:470:in `block in find_by_sql'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:470:in`collect!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:470:in `find_by_sql'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:112:in`to_a'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:376:in `find_first'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:122:in`first'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:263:in `find_by_attributes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1070:in`method_missing'
    from /task/user_setup.rb:74:in `new_user_setup'
    from /task/user_setup.rb:39:in`initialize'
    from /task/justa_worker.rb:48:in `new'
    from /task/justa_worker.rb:48:in`run'
    from /task/runner.rb:405:in `'

Answer (score 4):

First of all, iron_worker gem deprecated a while ago. Update your code to iron_worker_ng gem ( https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_ruby_ng ), if you can. This action will solve 99.9% issues with merging gems (it's primary reason of writing new gem)

Probable reason: gem version mismatch, mostly rails gems. activerecord/activesupport/etc

Try to:

1. Check again gem versions actually used
2. Manually set exact version (second parameter in merge_gem)
3. Use magic construction `gem 'mygem', '=0.1.2'` somewhere in ruby code